# Cannot display local window in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0

Currently, I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, but I have a problem:

I cannot view the process of my code, arrays and etc. in the Local Window. When I run the program I'm not able to see anything in there, it only displays something if the program crashes.

Please I need to fix that. I really want to view the process and logic behind my code.

Comment: I don't have a clue what you are asking. Try to make your question clearer.

Comment: Sir, I want to view the process in the Local Window. But, it doesn't display something. I'm currently working with my array algorithm, that's why I wanted to check the process of the Arrays.

Comment: @Hossein : No Sir, Its just a Windows Form Application.

Comment: The locals window will not show show you any values unless the program has stopped. Have you tried putting an breakpoint before the code that you are interested in and then step through your program to look at your values ?

Comment: @MarkHall : Ok, Sir. But I don't have any idea how to put breakpoints. Can you helo me Sir?

Comment: Set a breakpoint by clicking the left mouse button in the gray area left of the text editor on some valid source code line. A red "sphere" will show that a breakpoint is set.

Comment: Left click the left Margin next to where you want to stop your code. It should put a red circle there. The program will stop at the circle. then use F11 to step through it.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k80ex6de(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @MarkHall : Sir, I already put a breakpoint and run the program. But my arrays contains null. I don't know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said above the Locals Window is only updated when the program is stopped by the debugger. You can do that by using a breakpoint, which will make sure the program stops where you need it to, or by pressing the "Break All" button (Ctrl+Alt+Break).

To insert a break point you need to click to the side of the desired line of code (as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8pHF.png)). The code in that example is C++ but placing breakpoints is the same.

Comment: Done , Sir, but the local is still null. My array must store values on other array but it doesn't display by the local window.

Comment: Finished, I put many breakpoints.

Comment: How should be tell when you're not showing us any code?

Answer (score 0):

The locals window is updated only when your program is stopped by the debugger. Place a few breakpoints and you'll be able to see your locals properly.

Comment: Sir, How to put breakpoints?